# How to insert either, *, +, -, or / into string

Tags: ruby, random

I am building a program that chooses two random numbers between `100` and `1000` and asks to either multiply(`*`), divide(`/`), add(`+`), or subtract(`-`) the numbers given. Here is my code:

```
class Math_num
  problem = puts "What is #{rand(100..1000)} #{rand(100..1000)} "
end
```

This outputs something like this:

```
"What is 432(random number) 783(random number)"
```

I would like to randomly insert either the divide symbol(`/`), the add symbol(`+`), the minus symbol(`-`), or the multiply symbol(`*`) in between the two random numbers. Like so:

```
"What is 432(random number) + 783(random number)"
```

What would I have to do to achieve this?

Comment: FWIW: class names should be in [`CamelCase`](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide#camelcase-classes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
class Math_num
    operator = ['+', '-', '*', '/'].sample
    problem ="What is #{rand(100..1000)} #{operator} #{rand(100..1000)}?"
    puts problem
end
```

The `sample` method returns a random sample of `n` elements of an array, in this case a single random element.

If you want to be able to check your answers, a little restructuring is a good idea.

```
class Math_num
    operator = ['+', '-', '*', '/'].sample
    num1 = rand(100..1000)
    num2 = rand(100..1000)
    problem = "What is #{num1} #{operator} #{num2}?"
    puts problem

    input = gets.to_i
    answer = num1.send(operator, num2)

    if input != answer
      puts "Incorrect, the answer was #{answer}."
    end
end
```

The method you might not have seen here is `send`, which can be called on (almost) all objects. The first argument is a method name (either as a string `"foo"` or symbol `:foo`), and the rest are arguments to that method. Writing `num1 + num2` is equivalent to writing `num1.send('+', num2)`, which is very convenient when you want to vary the operator called.

Also, be aware that `to_i` will return `0` for text that is not a number, so if the answer is `0` and you input `foo` it will count as correct.

Comment: Thank you for this, it was simple and well described! I have one more question though: How would I set it up so that I have to answer the question correctly? I would like to have the computer ask me for the correct answer to the question. For instance, it asks me what 401 + 200 equals and if I answer correctly "601" it returns "Correct!", but if I answer incorrectly, "600", it returns "Incorrect, the answer is 601." Thank you for your help.

Comment: @cremno Thanks, I forgot about the nullary method call.

Comment: @zappdapper I added a little more, let me know if that doesn't help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an array with the operators and use [`Array#sample`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Array.html#method-i-sample) to get a random operator. Then use [`Object#send`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Object.html#method-i-send) to apply the operator to the numbers if you want the result:

```
OPERATORS = ['+', '-', '/', '*']

def random_number(first = 100, last = 1000)
  rand(first..last)
end

operator = OPERATORS.sample
number1 = random_number
number2 = random_number
puts "#{number1} #{operator} #{number2}?"
puts number1.send(operator, number2)
```